# Having trouble understanding a portion of code

Tags: c, algorithm, bit

I have this problem:

> You have n problems. You have estimated the difficulty of the i-th one
>   as integer ci. Now you want to prepare a problemset for a contest,
>   using some of the problems you've made.
>
> A problemset for the contest must consist of at least two problems.
>   You think that the total difficulty of the problems of the contest
>   must be at least l and at most r. Also, you think that the difference
>   between difficulties of the easiest and the hardest of the chosen
>   problems must be at least x.
>
> Find the number of ways to choose a problemset for the contest.
>
> Input The first line contains four integers n, l, r, x (1 ≤ n ≤ 15,
>   1 ≤ l ≤ r ≤ 109, 1 ≤ x ≤ 106) — the number of problems you have, the
>   minimum and maximum value of total difficulty of the problemset and
>   the minimum difference in difficulty between the hardest problem in
>   the pack and the easiest one, respectively.
>
> The second line contains n integers c1, c2, ..., cn (1 ≤ ci ≤ 106) —
>   the difficulty of each problem.
>
> Output Print the number of ways to choose a suitable problemset for
>   the contest.

I tried to solve it but unfortunately I couldn't do it. I asked a friend to give me an idea and he solved it for me but i don't understand something:

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int a[25], l, r, x, i, j, n, ans;
int main(){
    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &n, &l, &r, &x);
    for(i=0; i<n; i++) scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    for(i=0; i<(1<<n); i++){
        int s = 0;
        int max = 0, min = 1e9;
        for(j=0; j<n; j++){
            if((i>>j)&1){
                if(a[j] > max) max = a[j];
                if(min > a[j]) min = a[j];
                s += a[j];
            }
        }
        if(l <= s && s <= r && max-min >= x) ans++;
    }
    printf("%d", ans);
    return 0;
}
```

1. Why is he going through that array till `i<(1<<n)` if he only got n elements?
2. Why he does this: `if((i>>j)&1)` ?

I know that `1<<n` is the equivalent of multiplying by a power of two and `1>>n` is equivalent to integer division by 2^n but it makes no sense here.

Comment: Here is a question for you.  Why don't you ask your friend why he did what he did?

Comment: @NathanOliver that's sorta besides the point. I was going to downvote this, but he's presented his question well, given us a SCCEE, and took the time to format most of it.

Comment: @NathanOliver I don't know if you'll belive me but he's going to the countryside for a while :) I wish he could explain to me so that i weren't supposed to post this here..

Comment: @TankorSmash I am not discrediting the question.  I just figured if the OP knows the source then why not ask the source.  Since the OP explained the the source is away then that explains why they came here.

Comment: Perfectly right @NathanOliver, now please take a look at the code!

Comment: The code looks like C and not like C++ to me.

Comment: Dude, can you explain me those things please?! I'm pretty sure you understand the code ! @Adalee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have n possible problems, and each one can either be included or excluded from the problem set. This means that there are 2 options for every problem, so with n problems there are 2^n options for creating possible problem sets.

With the line `for(i=0; i<(1<<n); i++)` you are iterating all these possible problems sets, each one identified by an integer between 0 and 2^n - 1. Next, we need to identify which problems belong to a certain problem set, and we have the integer which represents it.

To do that, we take the binary representation of that integer. It will have `n` bits, and lets say that each bit corresponds to a problem: if it is 1 then the problem is included, otherwise it is not. This is what the line `if((i>>j)&1)` is doing: it checks if the bit in position `j` inside the integer `i` is equal to 1, which means that the corresponding problem is included.

The rest is easier: from all the included problems, you calculate the minimum, maximum, and sum. Then, check if the sum `s` is in the valid range, and if the difference between the maximum and minimum is at least x.

Comment: Sounds like backtracking to me!

Comment: Well, it is a brute force approach.

Comment: Brute force is a general technique, which in general is not recommended, because it is slow. If you are interested in learning about algorithms, I would recommend taking [this course.](https://www.coursera.org/course/algo)